# Namespaces and free functions

Tags: c++, namespaces, global-namespace, non-member-functions

I have a free function, `foo`, defined in a namespace N. The header for `foo` is in the global include search path so anyone can call it by including `foo.h`.

`foo` calls another local, free function, `foo1`, which is defined in `foo.cpp`.

```
// foo.h
namespace N
{
    void foo();
} 


// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"

namespace
{
    // declare in the unnamed namespace?
    void foo1()
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}

namespace N
{
    // declare in namespace N?
    void foo1()
    {
        // do some stuff
    }

    void foo()
    {
        foo1();
    }

} // N
```

Should I put `foo1` in the unnamed namespace or in `namespace N`? Or doesn't it matter?

**UPDATE**

I want to limit the scope of `foo1` to `foo.cpp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a global namespace, but an anonymous one. Defining it there will only allow `foo1` to be used in that translation unit, so you can't declare it somewhere else and use it afterwards.

This will effectively limit its scope to `foo.cpp`. If that's your intention, declare it in an anonymous namespace.

If you want to be able to use it from outside, declare it in the global namespace or `N` (global namespace means you just leave it out of a namespace) - depending on where it makes sense.

```
void global_foo();

namespace
{
   void internal_linkage_foo();
}

namespace X
{
   void foo_from_x();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected my post. I should have said unnamed namespace rather than global namespace.

Comment: I do want to limit the scope of `foo` to `foo.cpp`. What is the benefit of declaring it in an anonymous namespace rather than in `N`?

Comment: @ksl The [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) states that you can only have one definition for a particular function. If you put `foo1` in namespace `N` and someone else also tries to put a function `foo1` in namespace `N` you will get a linker error. Even if those functions are not declared in a .h file. By putting it in the anonymous namespace you can be sure you will not get any conflicts.

Comment: @ChrisDrew that's not all. By putting it in an anonymous namespace, you make sure someone can't just declare it and then use it in a different file.